# opengl tall texture vs wide texture for memory locality

Tags: opengl, multidimensional-array, textures

A 2D Texture has two coordinates, x and y. To store a 2D array in 1D memory, the two possible formats are [x + y * width] and [x * height + y]. OpenGL has various confusing row-major/column-major conventions so I am unsure which of the two formats it uses. This is relevant because if a texture is used to store multiple images, such as in a sprite sheet or atlas, it is better to have the parts of an image located close together in memory. For example, if the format is [x + y * width] and we are using a very wide texture, then the GPU will have to skip through long parts of memory to find the texels it needs.

Thus: is a tall texture atlas superior to a wide texture atlas, or is it the other way around? Or do GPUs have no memory locality benefits?

Comment: "*OpenGL has various confusing row-major/column-major conventions so I am unsure which of the two formats it uses.*" 1) Matrix storage has nothing to do with texture storage. 2) OpenGL only has one matrix convention. 3) It's not particularly confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important aspect of a texture atlas is how many images can fit inside it. Even when it comes to texture atlases, you are far more likely to access adjacent texels than distant ones.

Think about it. Say you render 2 32x32 sprites. So that's 2 quads, in a single rendering call. Each quad will take up 32x32 pixels on the screen; that's 1024 pixels.

Locality matters; you're rendering from 1024 locally adjacent texels, then rendering from a different set of 1024 locally adjacent texels.

In any case, OpenGL does not expose you to the details of the GPU's image formats. You can ask for a particular size of texel and a number of channels. But you don't get any more details than that. The data you provide will be appropriately converted by the driver into the actual internal GPU data.

Typically, GPUs will swizzle textures in memory. This means rearranging data so that locality is preserved. That is, instead of storing texels as either `x + y * width` or `x * height + y`, they get stored in a more complex arrangement.

For example, the first 4 values would be texels 0,0; 0,1; 1,0; and 1,1. So a 2x2 block of texels is store in a single contiguous array of memory. That's an example of how swizzled texture storage works.

But this is all an implementation detail; there's nothing you can do to influence or affect this, and not even a low-level API like Vulkan allows you to directly load pre-swizzled texel data.